# Клиент серверное приложение, хранение данных

Tags: sql, клиент-сервер

Мое приложение должно быть клиент-серверным. Данные хранятся в СУБД на сервере.
При запросе с клиента СУБД возвращает набор записей.
Данные программа получает, и хранит в модели (массив данных) таблицы.
В какой то момент пользователь решит добавить 10тыс строк в таблицу.
При этом никаких запросов к СУБД не происходит, не нажав на кнопку сохранить.
В какой то момент отключается питание, не важно как, но компьютер будет выключен, при том что данные все еще в памяти.
Вопрос в том как эти данные не потерять
1) делать сразу sql запрос на обновление данных
2) записывать их сразу же после добавление на локальную бд
после отправки очищать локальную бд или взять данные если комп был принудительно отключен. При этом данная локальная бд должна быть защищена паролем...

Comment: Ответ содержится в самом вопросе. Если можно данные сразу обновлять в БД - так и делаем. Если нельзя (нет соединения или ещё не все введены) - сохраняем локально. Что именно использовать локально - файл, реляционную СУБД, nosql - зависит от обстоятельств.

Comment: Если работаем с субд, то почему локально не использовать то же

Comment: А если СУБД **очень** дорогая и тяжеловесная?

Comment: А какое это имеет значение, я же не буду всю субд на клиентскую часть переписывать. Мне нужно работать с одной таблицей и кешировать данные которые должны быть записаны или были изменены. Ну если в таблице 1 млн строк, это не так много...

Answer (score 0):

Если есть возможность, то лучше все данные сразу отправлять в базу с пометкой, что это еще не завершенная правка. У меня на работе это делается установкой у записи статуса "черновик". Такие записи видит только ее автор. После того как пользователь уверен что все ввел правильно, записи получают статус "в работе" и становятся видны всем. Это позволяет в случае выхода из строя клиентской машины или целого филиала перейти в другой и продолжить работу там, просто залогинившись под своей учеткой.

Добавляя долговременное хранение данных где-то кроме сервера вы получаете не клиент-серверную, а распределенную (многосерверную) асимметричную архитектуру. Это может быть оправдано только если канал связи слишком неустойчивый, медленный и/или дорогой (например GPRS в филиале в глухой тайге). И все равно в таких условиях проще сделать симметричную архитектуру, т.е. поднять такой же точно сервер БД с такой же структурой базы, которая будет синхронизироваться с базой центрального сервера. Как именно организовывать синхронизацию - зависит от ваших ограничений на частоту и объем передаваемых данных.

Все остальные варианты имеют либо проблемы с безопасностью (если мы храним данные в быстрой файловой базе данных), либо сложны в администрировании и поддержке (менять пароли и вносить правки типа добавления нового столбца в нескольких разных базах одновременно), либо не обладают отказоустойчивостью (если данные хранятся в памяти). А то и обладают несколькими перечисленными проблемами одновременно.